# An example of $\min_{x } \max_{y} f(x,y) > \max_{y} \min_{x} f(x,y)$ over the unity simplex

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider
> $$\Delta_m := \bigg\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m : x_i \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^mx_i=1 \bigg\}$$
>
> and analogously $\Delta_n$. Find an examaple of a function $f: \Delta_m \times \Delta_n  
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$\min_{x \in \Delta_m} \max_{y \in \Delta_n} f(x,y) > \max_{y \in \Delta_n} \min_{x \in \Delta_m} f(x,y).$$

Unfortunately I can not find such a counterexample, could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bijection $\lambda\colon [0,1]\to \Delta_2$, so it suffices to find an example $f$ on the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Hint: Come up with a function that has its maximum on a curve in the unit square and think about how to orient that curve.